# How to allow gasses to flow through my base?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I've build airflow tiles but gasses get stuck in the wrong places anyway:
- Hydrogen gets stuck in my coal power generator room.
- Oxygen gets stuck in my oxygen generator room.
- Oxygen gets stuck in whatever room I transport it to.
- Hydrogen gets stuck in barracks, making it hard for dupes to sleep.

There's almost no natural spread of the different gasses, it's almost like I have to build gas pumps in every room. This makes no sense and I haven't see it in other people's bases. What am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Could you add a picture without the filter? This would help us see the distribution of different gases

Comment: Use pumps and ducts to pump gasses to places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had similar issues when I haven't had enough oxygen production.  The blue areas suggest to me that you might not be producing enough oxygen.  Gases will diffuse throughout your base over time, but the relative weights end being the most important factor.  They also sometimes have trouble going through one-wide spaces, as two gases can't occupy the same space and they'll 'fight' over it.

A couple of things you might try:

- Spreading out oxygen generation.  This works well if you're using Algae Deoxydizers or Terrariums, as your dupes can handle delivery of the necessary materials.
- Gas pumps from oxygen generation to other rooms.  I see you're doing this, but I think it would work better with a higher production level.
- More airflow tiles, including over the doors.  Airflow tiles over the doors will let lighter gases into the shaft.  I find that my main shaft is typically the main conduit for gases going up or down.  Definitely recommend the 3-wide shaft for that reason.

Comment: Thanks, I do sort of have a 3-wide shaft, I guess that's easier when you use airflow tiles for the balcony of each level. Things have been going better as I've been using more airflow tiles, indeed above doors.